# Postgres - Fetching one row only for a One to Many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two Tables in Postgres. There is a ONE TO MANY relationship between them.

**Manager Table**

```
Id    Designation  
1     Manager
```

**TeamMember Table**

```
Id    Designation  Report_To (ManagerId) 
4     INFRA ENG    1
2     SOFT ENG     1
3     TEAM LEAD    1
```

I have to fetch the records in such a way that I get only ONE ROW for a Manager with Designation of TeamMember as separate column, something like this:

**Result:**

```
ManagerId    INFRA  SOFT  TEAM
1            4      2     3
```

I tried with LEFT JOIN but it gives me 3 rows.

Any help would he highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select report_to as manager_id, 
    max(id) filter(where designation = 'INFRA ENG') as infra,
    max(id) filter(where designation = 'SOFT ENG')  as soft,
    max(id) filter(where designation = 'TEAM LEAD') as team
from teammember 
group by report to
```

Note that you don't need to bring the `manager` table to get the result that you are showing. But if you want it for some other reason, you can `join`:

```
select m.*, 
    max(tm.id) filter(where tm.designation = 'INFRA ENG') as infra,
    max(tm.id) filter(where tm.designation = 'SOFT ENG')  as soft,
    max(tm.id) filter(where tm.designation = 'TEAM LEAD') as team
from manager m
inner join teammember tm on tm.report_to ) m.id
group by m.id
```